# Hiding info from layer panel mouse over

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have QGIS linked to PostgreSQL but when I add layers from the db onto the project, people can easily see the user by simply mousing over the layer (which is the master user) so I need to hide it.

How to do this?

Comment: No, you need to create a viewer role to use in QGIS